# Wrong Ref Being Used/Accessed in Reusable Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I have tried everything I can think of to get these refs to play nicely together, but no dice.

I have 5 different Highcharts being rendered on the same page.  All of them have their own React components.  In each of those components, there is a `useRef(null)` that is being used and then being passed down to the children.  The issue that I am having is when I export the data from the Highchart, it always uses the last chart's ref on the page for the export.

Parent Component:

```js
export const JobsChart = ({ usageDataObject }: { usageDataObject: UsageResponse }): ReactElement => {
    const jobsChartRef = useRef(null);

    ...

    return (
        <div>
            <ExportChartButton ref={jobsChartRef} />
            <ChartContainer
                usageDataObject={usageDataObject}
                chartTitle={chartTitle}
                chartType={chartType}
                colorMap={colorMap}
                seriesNames={seriesNames}
                optionsOverride={options}
                ref={jobsChartRef}
            />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Export Chart Component:

```js
import { jsx } from '@emotion/core';
import { forwardRef, ReactElement, useRef } from 'react';
import ReactTooltip from 'react-tooltip';

import * as S from './export-chart.styles';
import { ReactComponent as MoreActionsIcon } from './icons/more-actions.svg';

type TooltipRef = { tooltipRef: null } | null;

type Props = {};

export const ExportChart = forwardRef(
    (_props: Props, chartRef): ReactElement => {
        const tooltipRef = useRef(null);

        const hideTooltip = () => {
            const current: TooltipRef = tooltipRef.current;
            if (current) (current as any).tooltipRef = null;
            ReactTooltip.hide();
        };

        const exportChart = (type: string) => {
            const chart: any = chartRef;

            if (chart.current) {
                (chartRef as any).current.exportChart(type);
                hideTooltip();
            }
        };

        const exportCSV = () => exportChart('csv');
        const exportXLSX = () => exportChart('xlsx');

        return (
            <div css={S.exportButtonWrapper}>
                <button data-tip={true} data-for="registerTip" data-event="click">
                    <MoreActionsIcon />
                </button>
                <ReactTooltip
                    css={S.exportDropdown}
                    data-testid="export-dropdown"
                    ref={tooltipRef}
                    globalEventOff="click"
                    id="registerTip"
                    place="bottom"
                    effect="solid"
                    type="light"
                    border={true}
                    offset={{ top: 5, left: 38 }}
                    clickable={true}
                >
                    <span>
                        <button onClick={exportCSV}>Download CSV</button>
                        <button onClick={exportXLSX}>Download XLSX</button>
                    </span>
                </ReactTooltip>
            </div>
        );
    }
);
```

Chart Container Component:

```js
export const ChartContainer = forwardRef(
    ({ usageDataObject, chartTitle, chartType, colorMap, seriesNames, optionsOverride }: Props, ref): ReactElement => {

...
        const chartRef = useRef(null);
        useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
            exportChart(type: string) {
                const chart = (chartRef as any).current.chart;

                if (type === 'csv') {
                    chart.downloadCSV();
                } else if (type === 'xlsx') {
                    chart.downloadXLSX();
                }
            }
        }));

        return <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={chartOptions} ref={chartRef} />;
...
});
```

So, the issue lies in the exportChart within the Chart Container component.  No matter what I do, the `chartRef` is always pointing to the last of the 5 chart's ref that is being rendered.

I think I am missing something in how the refs are getting scoped.

Please let me know if there is any further information I can provide to help diagnose this issue.  I tried to abbreviate the code in some places just to make things easier to follow as a lot of the abbreviated code is just setting options for Highcharts and what not.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you reproduce your case with the sample data on some online editor?